# How do I grab a process's start time in minutes?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I need to get a process's starting time in minutes (and minutes only.)

I already have code to get a **directory's** Date Modified time:

```
[int]([datetime]::Now - (gci 'C:\Folder' -Force).LastWriteTime).TotalMinutes
```

How can I create something similar for processes that only grabs minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-Process` displays the start time for *some* processes which you can use to calculate the elapsed minutes. Note that `[int]` will always round to the nearest integer (minute).

Using the same method to calculate the minutes as your post, it would look like:

```
Get-Process -Name explorer | select name,starttime,@{N="Minutes elapsed";E={[int]([datetime]::Now - $_.StartTime).TotalMinutes}}
```

Outputs:

```
Name     StartTime           Minutes elapsed
----     ---------           ---------------
explorer 14/12/2018 02:46:00             991
```

Comment: Is there any way to remove the header/table and just have the Minutes elapsed?

Comment: @Quizzed: instead of the `select` call, use `ForEach-Object {[int]([datetime]::Now - $_.StartTime).TotalMinutes}`

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 5):

Not **ALL** processes have the property StartTime set, so:

```
Get-Process | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.StartTime){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Process = $_.Name
            RunsMinutes=[int]([datetime]::Now - $_.StartTime).TotalMinutes
        }
    }
}
```

will yield something like this:

```
Process                RunsMinutes
-------                -----------
avgnt                          631
Avira.Systray                  631
ClassicStartMenu               632
cmd                            246
conhost                        561
conhost                        246
conhost                        459
ctfmon                         632
dllhost                        632
explorer                       632
fdm                            631
firefox                        594
firefox                        631
...
```